# Developing a camera app using android studio and CameraX SDK, but EXIF data for images won't update properly

Tags: android, android-camerax

So the app I've developed uses the preview use case from the CameraX SDX to render what the back facing camera sees. This works fine, but where I have trouble is that the onclick method I developed for a "capture" button, can't seem to capture images.

The onCreate function

```
private lateinit var imageCapture: ImageCapture

    //CameraX Variables
    private  lateinit var cameraExecutor: ExecutorService
    private  lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    //Layout Variables
    private lateinit var viewImagesButton: Button
    private lateinit var captureButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, null, false)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        viewImagesButton = findViewById(R.id.viewImagesButton)
        captureButton = findViewById(R.id.captureButton)

        cameraExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
        requestPermission()
    }
```

The Functions that create the preview using cameraX

```
private fun requestPermission() {
        requestCameraPermissionIfMissing { granted ->
            if(granted){
                startCamera()
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Please Allow Permissions",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun requestCameraPermissionIfMissing(onResult: ((Boolean) -> Unit)) {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            onResult(true)
        }
        else{
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) {
                onResult(it)
            }.launch(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        }
    }

    private fun startCamera() {
        val processCameraProvider = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)
        processCameraProvider.addListener({
            try {
                val cameraProvider = processCameraProvider.get()
                val previewUseCase = buildPreviewUseCase()

                imageCapture = ImageCapture.Builder()
                    .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation())
                    .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                    .build();
                cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA, previewUseCase, imageCapture)
                captureButton.setOnClickListener {
                    onClick(imageCapture)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception){
                runOnUiThread {
                    Toast.makeText(this,e.message.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                Log.d("ERROR", e.message.toString())
            }
        },ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this))
    }

    private fun buildPreviewUseCase():Preview{
        return Preview.Builder().build().also { it.setSurfaceProvider(binding.previewView.surfaceProvider)}
    }
```

The onclick function having that can't seem to save the photos

```
private fun onClick(imageCapture:ImageCapture) {

        //Creating the file to save the image
        val photoDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        if (photoDir == null || !photoDir.isDirectory) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Invalid photo directory: $photoDir")
            return
        }
        Log.d("MainActivity", "photoDir: $photoDir")

        val date = Date()
        val timeStamp = date.time.toString()
        val photoFilePath = photoDir.absolutePath
        val photoFile = File("${photoDir.absolutePath}/${timeStamp}.jpg")
        photoFile.createNewFile()

        Log.d("MainActivity", "photoFilePath: ${photoDir.absolutePath}")
        Log.d("MainActivity", "photoFile.exists(): ${photoFile.exists()}")

        //Establishing the file options for the image we are going to save
        val outputFileOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photoFile).build()

        //Attempting to save
        imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {

                override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    // insert your code here.
                    runOnUiThread {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Capturing succeeded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
                override fun onError(error: ImageCaptureException)
                {
                    // insert your code here.

                    runOnUiThread {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "Error capturing image: ${error.message}", error)
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Capturing failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            })
    }
```

So in my attempts to debug, I found that the log cat repeatedly displays this error

```
Error capturing image: Failed to update Exif data
                                                                                                    androidx.camera.core.ImageCaptureException: Failed to update Exif data
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.JpegBytes2Disk.updateFileExif(JpegBytes2Disk.java:138)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.JpegBytes2Disk.apply(JpegBytes2Disk.java:68)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.JpegBytes2Disk.apply(JpegBytes2Disk.java:52)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode.processOnDiskCapture(ProcessingNode.java:172)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode.processInputPacket(ProcessingNode.java:147)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode.lambda$transform$0$androidx-camera-core-imagecapture-ProcessingNode(ProcessingNode.java:110)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to copy original file to temp file
                                                                                                        at androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface.saveAttributes(ExifInterface.java:4732)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.Exif.save(Exif.java:176)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.JpegBytes2Disk.updateFileExif(JpegBytes2Disk.java:136)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.JpegBytes2Disk.apply(JpegBytes2Disk.java:68) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.JpegBytes2Disk.apply(JpegBytes2Disk.java:52) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode.processOnDiskCapture(ProcessingNode.java:172) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode.processInputPacket(ProcessingNode.java:147) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode.lambda$transform$0$androidx-camera-core-imagecapture-ProcessingNode(ProcessingNode.java:110) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4) 
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Not a directory
                                                                                                        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively0(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(UnixFileSystem.java:317)
                                                                                                        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2007)
                                                                                                        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2053)
                                                                                                        at androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface.saveAttributes(ExifInterface.java:4718)
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.Exif.save(Exif.java:176) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.JpegBytes2Disk.updateFileExif(JpegBytes2Disk.java:136) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.JpegBytes2Disk.apply(JpegBytes2Disk.java:68) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.JpegBytes2Disk.apply(JpegBytes2Disk.java:52) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode.processOnDiskCapture(ProcessingNode.java:172) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode.processInputPacket(ProcessingNode.java:147) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode.lambda$transform$0$androidx-camera-core-imagecapture-ProcessingNode(ProcessingNode.java:110) 
                                                                                                        at androidx.camera.core.imagecapture.ProcessingNode$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:4) 
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

As far as I can tell the issue seems to be something with the EXIF data of the image but no matter how I try to set up the metadata, the error persist.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. Which version of CameraX are you using? Also it would be nice to show the full logcat error.